ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask' VS code
I have the following code:
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask("website")


@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")


app.run(debug=True)


This on vs code outputs the following:
[Running] python -u "c:\Users\Jumad\Desktop\Projects\Weather API\main.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Jumad\Desktop\Projects\Weather API\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask, render_template
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'

On pycharm it works fine but it is heavy on my machine so i prefer running it on vs code instead. I've tried all related solutions in this platform but none of them work.
I'm running python 3.12 and the Flask module is also installed in the .venv folder
main.py and the .venv are both in the same directory, "Weather API"
Please help in the most simplest way possible, thankyou

when setting a project with pycharm it sometimes creates it's own environment for that project, which in this case is not the same VSCode is using. If VSCode is using the system python, the easiest solution is probably installing flask in the system python. Do pip install flask from a console and it should work. If you don;t want that, then you need to figure out which env pycharm is using and configure VSCode to use the same environment

in VSCode runs print( os.executable ) to get /full/path/to/python and use it to install modules /full/path/to/python -m pip install flask. if you have venv which works in PyCharm then you may need to use print( os.executable ) to get correct path to Python in this venv and later set this path in some settings in VSCode for current project
